# How to cite author and date, but only date in brackets with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

How can I change a citation like

> Acharya et al. 2002 found that apples can come in a variety of colors.

to one with a brackets only around the date

> Acharya et al. (2002) found that apples can come in a variety of colors.

I'm using the `chicago-authordate` style, and couldn't find a relevant command in the [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/info/biblatex-cheatsheet/biblatex-cheatsheet.pdf).

I can produce the desired result by citing once for the author and once for the date, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    citestyle=chicago-authordate
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{acharya_analysis_2002,
    title = "An Analysis of Apples",
    author = "Acharya, Alice and Benson, Bob and Carrey, Catalina and Duvet, Dorian",
    date = 2002
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib} 

\begin{document}
\cite{acharya_analysis_2002} (\citedate{acharya_analysis_2002}) found that apples can come in a variety of colors.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `biblatex` package's `\textcite` directive is what you're looking for. (This directive is listed in the middle column of the first page of the "Biblatex Cheat Sheet" document you mention in your query.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@misc{acharya_analysis_2002,
    title = "An Analysis of Apples",
    author = "Acharya, Alice and Benson, Bob and Carrey, Catalina and Duvet, Dorian",
    date = 2002
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib} 

\begin{document}
\textcite{acharya_analysis_2002} found that apples can come in a variety of colors.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get *Author (Year)* citations in a `biblatex` author-year style is to use

```
\textcite
```

A manually-defined command like `\newcommand{\citedateparen}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citedate{#1})}` has several drawbacks:

1. It does not handle multiple citations particularly well. Try `\citedateparen{sigfridsson,worman}`.
2. In this simple form it does not handle pre- and postnotes (pages etc.) at all.
3. It can mess up citation and ibidem tracking (this depends on the style and its settings).

The correct way to define a new citation command that does all these things properly is via `\DeclareCiteCommand`. But this is not required here, since the desired command already exists.

---

Note that the styles of `biblatex-chicago` should usually be loaded via the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago` and not via `biblatex`. Additionally, the MWE threw errors because one can't easily combine the `style=alphabetic` (or `bibstyle=alphabetic`) with `citestyle=chicago-authordate` due to the internal structure of `chicago-authordate`. (It also looks weird.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  authordate,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document}
\textcite{sigfridsson} found that apples can come in a variety of colors.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998) found that apples can come in a variety of colors.]